# Regex for variable name before period in Sublime Text snippet

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

So I'm trying to write a snippet for Sublime Text 3 for `forEach` statements called on Objects.

```
//what I have written at the point where the snippet is triggered
myObject.forEa

// what should appear after triggering the snippet
Array.prototype.forEach.call(myObject, function(){

})
```

The problem here is to capture `myObject` in the regex of the snippet, so that I can reuse it when writing the snippet.

So far, I have a regex that would capture anything suitable for being the `myObject` that I need: `(\w|\.)+\b\.`. But I need to capture the exact one that is before the cursor.

You can also use a few environment variables such as the content of the cursor's line, the horizontal position of the cursor... [Official documentation for snippets in Sublime Text](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#environment-variables).

Can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as I know, **you can use the variable *$TM_CURRENT_LINE* to get the content of the line, but the only thing that gets replaced is the tab trigger (*forEa*)**, the rest of the line will still be there. I give you an example and an alternative.

### Example (doesn't work as expected):

```
<content><![CDATA[Array.prototype.forEach.call(${TM_CURRENT_LINE/^[ \t]*(\S*)\.$/\1/g}, function(){
    ${1:functionConent}
})]]></content>
```

Changes

```
myObject.forEa
```

To

```
myObject.Array.prototype.forEach.call(myObject, function(){
    functionConent
})
```

So, you can use the line content but `myObject.` is still at the begining of the line.

### Alternative (not exactly what you want but works properly):

I suppose you know how to do it this way, but I think it is better to do it the easy way:

```
<content><![CDATA[Array.prototype.forEach.call(${1:object}, function(){
    ${2:functionConent}
})]]></content>
```

This changes

```
forEa
```

To

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(object, function(){
    functionConent
})
```

After the change the focus is in the first field (the object), so you can write it éasily, and then you can move to the next field (function content) using *tab*.

Comment: Do you have documentation for this behavior?

Comment: @MattDMo What behavior? If its possible or not to replace all the line when using tab trigger?

Comment: Never mind. I was asking about `$TM_CURRENT_LINE` not being able to be replaced, but I've just been doing some experimenting and it seems to be true, at least in the latest dev build of ST3. I think the only way to *really* solve the OP's problem is via plugin. I'll see what I can put together...

Comment: @MattDMo Ok, anyway I don't have any documentation about it.